# Как вернуть HashMap

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Код с сокращениями, тут суть)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Map<Integer, String> mapTrackFile = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        while (sc.hasNextLine()){
            next = sc.nextLine();
            if(next.contains(ABBREVIATYRA)){
                mapTrackFile = Main.recordDataTrackOrMap(sc, next);
            } else if(next.contains(STARTS_OF_FRAGMENT)){
                db.processString (koltrack, mapTrackFile, mapBD, count, sc);
            }
       }
    static Map recordDataTrackOrMap(Scanner sc, String next) {
        Map<Integer, String> mapTrackFile = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        //тут нахождение нужных параметров
        mapTrackFile.put(number, abbreviatura.trim());
        return mapTrackFile;
    }
```

MapTrack берётся из файла, у меня получается так, что записывается только последняя пара ключ - значение, ключи у всех разные 100%, то есть перезаписи не происходит, 
Что я не так понимаю? Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так Вы же в методе recordDataTrackOrMap каждый раз возвращаете новую карту для ключ/значение и присваиваете ее в методе main.
Варианта решения 2:
1. Сделать

```
    Map<Integer, String> mapTrackFile
```

из метода main полем класса и убрать

```
    Map<Integer, String> mapTrackFile = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

из recordDataTrackOrMap
2. Передавать mapTrackFile из метода main как параметр в метод recordDataTrackOrMap, но опять же

```
    Map<Integer, String> mapTrackFile = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

убрать из метода recordDataTrackOrMap

Comment: Дааа!! Спасибо большое! Было глупо конечно с моей стороны